# Array of objects property extraction loop shorthand

Tags: javascript, arrays

**Scenario:**

I need the same property from every object in an array.

**Example:** [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0a6kqc4j/)

```
var texts = [];
var arr = [{text:"first"}, {text:"second"}]
arr.forEach(item => {
    texts.push(item.text);
});
console.log(text); // >(2) [ "first", "second" ]
```

**Question:**

Is there a "shorterhand" version of this concept?

eg. `arr.childPropFilter("text")`

Comment: arr.map(item => item.text);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use map() to return a new array based on iterating original

```
var texts = arr.map(o => o.text)
```

Answer (score 1):

You mean something like this?

```
console.log(arr.map(t => t.text));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use **[`Array.prototype.map()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)** like this:

```
var texts = arr.map(function(obj){
  return obj.text;
});
```

**Demo:**

```js
var arr = [{text:"first"}, {text:"second"}]
var texts = arr.map(function(obj){
  return obj.text;
});
console.log(texts);
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes.try with [`Array#map()`](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiql5j2sobVAhUHMI8KHQA2AwMQFggnMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.mozilla.org%2Fen%2Fdocs%2FWeb%2FJavaScript%2FReference%2FGlobal_Objects%2FArray%2Fmap&usg=AFQjCNHaY16WQvsRJFKI1AN9YJUvUNjsCg) .Its return the new array

```js
var arr = [{text:"first"}, {text:"second"}]
var texts =arr.map(item => item.text);

console.log(texts);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a common need, and libraries often supply such a function:

**Ramda - [`pluck`](http://ramdajs.com/docs/#pluck)**:

```
pluck('text', arr)
```

**Underscore - [`pluck`](http://underscorejs.org/#pluck)**:

```
pluck(arr, 'text')
```

**lodash - [`map`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#map)**:

```
map(arr, 'text')
```

Note that lodash did have a `pluck` as well, but [chose to remove it](https://github.com/lodash/lodash/wiki/Changelog#jan-12-2016--diff--docs) in favor of an alternative usage of `map`.  So this is a common abstraction that you might decide to keep around.  The most common name would be `pluck`, and it's quite easy to write:

```
const pluck = (prop) => (list) => list.map(obj => obj[prop]);

pluck('test')(arr);
```